# iCloud says Password is Wrong Even Though I Know It's Right

Tags: icloud, password

iCloud says that my password is wrong - even though I know it's right.

Here's whats happened: Yesterday, I reset my iCloud password. Got the reset email, changed password. Tried to log in to the account, didn't accept it. I thought that maybe my finger had slipped typing in the password (twice). I called support, got the reset email.

Now, here's the really, really weird thing: I wanted to make sure I got the password right - so I typed my password into TextEdit, copied it into the reset fields and reset the password. After reseting it, I immediately went to icloud.com and tried to log in using the copied password from TextEdit. The passwords are the same. iCloud won't let me in.

Comment: Is your password really really long or does it contain any special characters?

Comment: @NathanGreenstein It's about 12 chars long. Contains one special character and a number, capita and lowercase letters.

Comment: Have you quit your browser, dumping cache and cookies, and Restarted your machine before going to iCloud.com? I would also check your keychain entry.

Comment: When you copied from TextEdit, you probably inadvertently copied a empty space with it (usually before the password). check for that.

Comment: @Borderline Nope - Even if I did, it would still have been the same for each paste - No?

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand you are using paste and not typing the password even after the account was set up.

Comment: And you can not see the password you are pasting (typing) so you do not know what is in the password field.

Comment: The following is bit elaborate (but even me can do it)

Comment: Having the same issue. I pasted the password both from KeePass and from notepad. I know the password was right because I only set it last week, and it was accepted when I re-typed it into the phone. I finally got past it by manually typing it, not pasting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it figured out. Kind of.

After two (!) support calls to Apple, two password reset emails, and a bunch of copy and pastes later, I can get in.

I still don't know what caused it, but I suspect there was a bad network configuration of some sort on my end.

Comment: It's not a network issue on your end, it is 100% a bug. I'm a network engineer.

Answer (score 11):

Not a solution just a verification.
Since you can not see the password, that you pasted or typed I sugest to verify what is in the password field.

For that
Open iCloud in Chrome
In the log in paste your password- But DO NOT try to log in.

Now to make it visible do following:
Right click on the password field and select "Inspect Element"

That will open a new window that looks like this

[image]

Move the cursor on the password field:
there will be a highlighted line in the bottom window as you can see:

Right click on the highlighted line and select 
Edit Attribute

Now it will highlight the word "type", now you write "show" instead "type"

Magic, now it will show what is in you password field.

Comment: I am sure there is better and faster way to do this, but I am a dummy.

Comment: I'm sure this is the best way to - really quite simple (I'm an iOS dev anyway). I'm talking to Support over the phone currently. They seem quite interested.

Comment: Why type=>show, not password=>text?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem.  I tried to enter iCloud with the same Apple ID and password that I use to (successfully) log into the App store.   Then I reset it.   Actually there's a bug on the site that asks for your birthdate, but leaves off the year, so no matter what you put in, it's always wrong.  I was finally able to reset the password.   I tried logging in with the new password, but it wouldn't let me.  I went to the App store and used the new password to successfully log in again.